# Regex optional doesn't seem to make sense

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
^[-]?(0|(([1-9]|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}){1}(\[0-9]{3}){0,})),(([0-9]{2})|\-\-)$
```

And used this tester, https://www.debuggex.com.

I don't quite understand this regex, because I just copied and pasted it, but via the tester I tried to get what's going on there. I did, except for one part. The graphic tells me, that this is group 4: `(\[0-9]{3}){0,})`

I can't completely erase it, then it won't work anymore, but the `\[0-9]{3}` part I can delete, and the expression still matches. Also it seems that group 4 is always walked around, according to the graphic when making input.

So my question is, is this part really necessary? And if, how? I don't see what it does.

Comment: What is this regex even supposed to do? What, precisely, does "won't work anymore" mean? What language's regexes are you using? (Regex capabilities differ from language to language.)

Comment: doesnt amke any sense to me without more context.

Comment: I'm using Java. It should match numbers like 123,45 or 12,34 or 0,12 etc. This one part doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{0,}` part of `(stuff){0,}` says to match what's inside the `()` a minimum of zero times, with no specified maximum, which is the equivalent of saying `(stuff)*`. So it really doesn't matter whether or not your test string contains the `stuff` inside the `()`, but if it does, the `stuff` will get captured in capturing group 4.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy

Comment: Thanks, the link to the doc actually helped the most. I will keep in mind to pay more attention to this while reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `\[0-9]{3}` needs to change to just `[0-9]{3}`.  The `\[` is resulting in a literal `[` instead of a character group, which is likely not intended.

There may be other problems with this regex as well, but it's hard to propose a solution without knowing your desired specifications.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but still, I can't see what it does. Without it the expression still matches everything like, 123,45 or 12,34 or 0,12 etc.

Comment: Well, it is possible that the matching groups are going to be used later on in the code.  Group 3 is just the digits before the first separation.  Group 4 will contain any string of digits whose length is divisible by 3, and would need a separation between each set of 3 digits.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Figured it out by now. It actually captures, 0,12 1,23 12,34 123,45 separately and numbers like 1234,56 and more digits with this. But they only get to this part if the count is divisible by 3, yes. So this whole regex is needlessly long. I got it down to this now. With this only numbers with 3 digits before the separation are possible. '^[-]?(0|[1-9]|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}),(([0-9]{2})|\-\-)$'